# Displaying Images from Server Folder C#/JavaScript/MVC4

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

So i'm attempting to use AJAX to pull a JSON file containing the file names of images on the server. So far the JSON pulls the needed file listings (paths to the actual image in the folder) and returns it to the page and then the page displays them all fine and dandy BUT it doesn't actually display the images. When the innerHTML of the div is edited to add the images, the image src comes up as "about:blank" and it's not making much sense to me as when I do an "alert" to check the inner html of the div after all the content has been added, it shows me the full server path of the image in the src. Below is the code, could someone possible give me an explanation to this bizarre occurrence. I appreciate any and all of your assistance :).

```
// Javascript / HTML on page
<div id="dogphotos">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            url: '/Assets/GetDogPhotos',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
                {
                    document.getElementById('dogphotos').innerHTML += '<img src="' + data[i] + '" style="width:90px; height:90px;"/><br><br>';
                }
                alert(document.getElementById('dogphotos').innerHTML);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

// Controller 
        public JsonResult GetDogPhotos()
        {
            return Json(Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Assets/Images/Dogs"), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
        }
```

[image: This is the final result]

Comment: your web browser is trying to get an image from c:\users\... on the server.  That's a local address, so it's going to look for it locally.  You will need to use new System.Uri(path).AbsoluteUri to convert it to a valid link.  You will also need to place the images in a folder that is accessible by your website, not just anywhere on the server.

Comment: Shouldn't they be accessible to the site already if it's in debug mode under the project files? I would understand if I had them stored say on C:\Images and didn't grant permissions but they should have rights to retrieve the images from a local project folder. I will try the other suggestion though (and as well as see about doing maybe C:\Images to test the permissions). I'll let you know and appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Unfortunately that did not cure my issue. I see what you mean about using the correct protocol so that the browser knows how to get the image and where from but I've updated my code with that and it's still not displaying the images. Although I can copy and paste the source and it opens just fine in the browser... strangeness.

Comment: `code          public JsonResult GetDogPhotos()
        {
            List<string> Files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Assets/Images/Dogs"), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
            List<string> TotalFiles = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Files.Count; i++)
            {
                TotalFiles.Add(new Uri(Files[i]).AbsoluteUri);
            }
            return Json(TotalFiles, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        } code`